# Forwarding from Visualforce page to SF Setup page

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a custom UI visualforce (the user does not see SF UI at all). The URL on the page is [X].Salseforce.com/apex/mypage. I know I can use /secur.logout.jsp to have the user logout. I want the users to click on a link and be forwarded to the SF Setup page ([X].Salesforce.com/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp).

The problem I have is that the code we have assumes a /apex/ in front of the URL. I need to take that out from link.I need to How can I do that?

Comment: What issues are you having sending them to that URL?

Comment: We have "/apex/" hardcoded in the URL and need to get around it. Maybe something like ../Setup

Comment: Seems like an important piece of information for the question

Comment: Right! I added to the question

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm grossly mis-interpreting your question, a relative hyperlink to that URL does the job perfectly.

```
<a href="/setup/forcecomHomepage.apexp">Force.com Home Page</a>
```

Does something about this not work for your implementation?